# How do I make content conditional on domain name?

Tags: conditionals, advanced-conditionals

I am wrapping up an MSM build that has one domain and three subdomains. Each site has unique Analytics code.

Conditional code based on segment is very useful but I am not sure how to display conditional code based on domain name. It would be handy to use a segment_0, but that obviously does not work.

Is there some other conditional code that would enable display of the analytics code based on the domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional with `{site_id}` or `{site_short_name}`.

If you still want to set the condition based upon on the domain, you can use `{site_url}`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. It works perfectly.